# Is it possible to install the MaterialDesignThemes package once and be able to reference it on each and every other wpf project?

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget-package, material-design-in-xaml

I am new in *WPF* application development and I came across the *Material Design package*, I am using *Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.*

Every time I want to create a new *WPF* application I always go to 
`Project -> Manage NuGet Packages` and install the *MaterialDesignThemes* package for that specific project and when I am working on another project I need to do the same process again.

Is possible to only install this package once and somehow use it (or reference it) on all projects that I am creating as opposed to installing it with each and every new project I create?

I hope my question makes sense and I am asking this for the sake of being able to develop new material design *WPF* applications offline.

Answer (score 1):

They ask to use nugget to keep the package updated that way you can check versions and so on. But you can download the source code from *GitHub* and keep it on your machine or server you use it for. That way you can refer it from your machine and don’t need to download for every project you work.

**Project source**: https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/releases

In my opinion, I highly recommend download from nugget repository because it is easy to maintain and anyone else that code and the same project will find the package over there.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Project Template.

- VS2015: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx
- VS2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates

Another way of quickly installing nuget packages is using the Package Manager Console and use the `install-package` command. e.g. `install-package materialdesignthemes`